# Tomcat issue with "Unable to establish loopback connection"

Tags: tomcat7

My Tomcat is throwing error as unable to establish loopback connection thou I set the -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, but still it is showing the issue.

I am using windows 8.1 and jdk1.8.0_152.

I tried lot of issue on net but no help to resolve this.

```
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 28 2017 10:30:11 UTC
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.23.0
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 8.1
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.3
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_152-b16
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         H:\apache-tomcat-8.5.23
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         H:\apache-tomcat-8.5.23
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=H:\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\conf\logging.properties
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.567 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.567 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.567 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.567 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=H:\apache-tomcat-8.5.23
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.567 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=H:\apache-tomcat-8.5.23
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.567 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=H:\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\temp
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.567 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.567 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.14] using APR version [1.6.2].
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.567 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
28-Oct-2017 16:54:15.567 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
28-Oct-2017 16:54:16.602 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017]
28-Oct-2017 16:54:16.821 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
28-Oct-2017 16:54:37.852 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
 java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:94)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:171)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
    at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:227)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector(NioSelectorPool.java:66)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.open(NioSelectorPool.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:227)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:982)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:245)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:997)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:621)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:644)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Comment: I have uninstalled my tomcat and installed a tomcat 7.0.64,

Comment: But now a strange issue, log is not showing any error and tomcat is running. but From browser, its is not responding here I am attaching my log.

Comment: INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT has finished in 107 ms
Oct 28, 2017 6:02:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8082"]
Oct 28, 2017 6:02:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8083"]
Oct 28, 2017 6:02:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1657 ms

Comment: This page can’t be displayed

•Make sure the web address http://127.0.0.1:8082 is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.